# Using coalesce and joins to get data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables. The first table 'Status_Mapping' has following columns

```
Status_original  Status_Site
accepted         Call Verified
duplicate        Duplicate Leads
dq               DQ
```

'Lead_transaction' has the columns:

```
Lead_transaction_id   Rate   Status
  11                  0.01   accepted
  12                  0.02   accepted
  13                  0.01   duplicate
```

'Lead_Instance' table:

```
Lead_Instance_id   Lead_transaction_id   product_id  affiliate_id
 1                    11                   6            10
 2                    12                   7            11
 3                    13                   6            10
```

What I want to do is loop through the status_mapping table and get the count(lead_instance_id) and sum(rate) for each status and then site status from the previous table with product_id = 6 and affiliate_id = 10 My End result should be like

```
Total              Sum   Status
 1                 0.01   Call Verified
 1                 0.01   Duplicate Leads
 0                 0.00   DQ
```

SQL Attempt

```
SELECT S.status_site AS [Status]
    ,COALESCE(count(L.lead_instance_id), 0) AS [Total Occurrences]
    ,COALESCE(SUM(L.Rate), 0) AS [Rate Sum]
    ,COALESCE(li.product_id, 0) AS [Product_id]
    ,COALESCE(li.afid, 0) AS [AFFILIATE_id]
FROM Status_Mapping S
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_transactions L ON S.status_orignal = L.STATUS
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_instance li ON li.lead_instance_id = L.lead_instance_id
WHERE li.product_id = 6
    AND li.afid = 27
GROUP BY S.status_site
    ,li.product_id
    ,li.afid
```

Comment: Can you include your attempt at the SQL Statement?

Comment: SELECT  S.status_site AS [Status], 
        COALESCE(count(L.lead_instance_id), 0) AS [Total Occurrences], 
        COALESCE(SUM(L.Rate), 0) AS [Rate Sum],
    COALESCE(li.product_id, 0) AS [Product_id],
    COALESCE(li.afid, 0) AS [AFFILIATE_id]
FROM Status_Mapping S
LEFT OUTER JOIN lead_transactions L ON S.status_orignal = L.Status
LEFt OUTER JOIN lead_instance li on li.lead_instance_id = L.lead_instance_id
where li.product_id = 6 and li.afid = 27
GROUP BY S.status_site,li.product_id,li.afid

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Use the edit functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    count(lt.Lead_transaction_id) as Total,
    coalesce(sum(lt.Rate), 0) as "Sum",
    sm.Status_Site as "Status"
from
    Status_Mapping sm
    left outer join
    (
        select lt.Lead_transaction_id, lt.Status, lt.Rate
        from
            Lead_transaction lt inner join Lead_instance li
                on li.Lead_transaction_id = lt.Lead_transaction_id
        where
            li.product_id = 6 and li.affiliate_id = 10
    ) lt
        on lt.Status = sm.Status_original
group by sm.Status_Site
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09c8b/1

The important part here is to do the inner join first so you can limit the results to the product and affiliate that you want and then afterward use an outer join to keep the full list of statuses. This is a case where you'll also occasionally see a right join instead of the nesting.

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped

Answer (score 0):

```
select Total = isnull(RES.Total,0),
       Summ = isnull(RES.Summ,0 ),
       Status = S.Status_Site
from Status_Mapping S
outer apply (
     select Total = count(*), Summ = sum(LT.Rate)
     from Lead_Instance LI
     join Lead_transaction LT 
          on LT.Lead_transaction_id = LI.Lead_transaction_id
     where LT.Status = S.Status
     and LI.product_id = 6 
     and LI.affiliate_id = 10 ) RES
```

Comment: Thats not working, it returns the same value of total and sum for all the rows

Comment: It's because the outer apply wasn't correlated on S. While you could get it to work there's no reason not just use a regular outer join here.

Comment: Ok, forgot to link to main from_table. Was tired. xcuse